# Set Integer To Zerofill In Sequel Migration (Ruby ORM)

Tags: ruby, orm, sequel, padrino

I'm trying to build a migration which would include an IP Address as a zero-filled unsigned integer.

My migration looks something like this currently but `zerofill: true` is not working

```
up do
  create table :ip do
    Integer :id, size: 7, default: nil
    Integer :ip_address_integer, size: 10, unsigned: true, zerofill: true
    varchar :scan_time, size: 32
    primary_key :id
  end
end
```

How would I make the IP address zero filled using the sequel ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequel does not support a `:zerofill` argument for defining columns.  You may want to just specify the type directly using something like:

```
column :ip_address_integer, 'integer(10) unsigned zerofill'
```